# How to zoom an slide the the screen in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, zooming

In my 2D Unity Project i had to use a zooming script in my main camera. Zooming works however, the camera just focuses on the middle of the scene. But I want to see the other parts of the scene which remain out of the field of view of camera. So, what should I add to my script in order to move over the scene when it's zoomed?

Here is my script for zooming. I threw it into the main camera.
[image]

This picture is the actual scene before zooming:
[image]

And this one is after zooming. Please pay attention that it directly focuses on the geometrical centre of the scene and doesn't allow me to move to another point on the scene(right, left, up, down).
[image]

Comment: It's simple, you must move the camera. and this movement is depend on your expect of it. You can access the mouse position by `Input.mousePosition` and devide it by `screen size` to get 0 to 1 values. for example if it was more that 0.5 in `y axis` it mean you must move the camera to right and so on.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you're looking to drag whilst zooming or use the mouse position be the center point of the zoom.

If it's the latter, you can do something like this;

```
float zoomSpeed = 5f;

void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel") != 0)
    {
        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition); RaycastHit point; Physics.Raycast(ray, out point, 25); Vector3 Scrolldirection = ray.GetPoint(5);

        float step = zoomSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
        mycamera.transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, Scrolldirection, Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel") * step);
    }
}
```